# Is there a way to see the total rep collected for the last year?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I know about https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2012-07-12/ where I can see:

```
#13853 week rank   
+23836 change 
586 total reputation 
12 week reputation
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to see reputation collected in a period of time (from date to date), or for example just per year, so I could see if I'm better/worse this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an exact number for past dates (The one @Lix gives can only get you an approximate), use the rep leagues.

Let's say you want to see the total rep you got in the last year. Click [the "year" tab](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow) in [the link you provided](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2012-07-12/), then click [prev year](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2011-01-01). Use the "type to find users" field to find yourself. Once you do, you can get a permalink [like this](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2011-01-01/534755?sort=reputationchange#534755) by hovering over.

Comment: reputation is not an exact science :P

Answer (score 7):

On [your Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/254997/nikola?tab=reputation) in the reputation tab, you can see your reputation plotted on a graph...

[image]

Depending how long you have been active on the site, you'll be able to see your reputation at a specific date and from there extract the data you are looking for.